# Calculated Control with Dynamic Date criteria

Tags: ms-access, calculated-field

I am trying to pass a value to a text box on an Access form with the code

```
DSum(" [CTRTable]![Count of CTRs] ", "CTRTable", "[Metric]= 'Total Contractors in RPT (All)' AND [Date] = DMax("[Date] ","CTRTable"),'mm/dd/yyy')" )
```

This sums the number of contractors For the Metric "Total Contractors in RPT (All)" at whatever the maximum date is in the report. So imagine someone going around an counting the number of contractors on a worksite every week.  I want a box that will give the latest count.

I have made this work with a number of other criteria but cannot get a clear answer on the syntax for dates.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes, try this:

```
DSum("[Count of CTRs]", "CTRTable", 
"([Metric]= 'Total Contractors in RPT (All)') AND 
([Date] = DMax(""[Date]"",""CTRTable""))")
```

Comment: because it is string inside the string. Haven't you eliminated some " or ) in sample ?